# Microsoft Client - Java Web Service

Tags: c#, web-services, visual-studio-2010

I have to consume a Java web service and want to do it using Microsoft Visual Web Developer in C#. I will be adding the endpoint of the web service as the web reference and hopefully go from there, however I am concerened if there will be any interoperability issues? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There won't be any interoperability issues if the Java web service respects the standards.

Comment: I see, so once the web reference has been added to the new client, how do I go about implementing the wsdl file and xsd file or does VS do this automatically?

Comment: VS generates proxy classes from the WSDL automatically. There's nothing you need to do manually other than instantiating the client and invoking the method.

Comment: I see, so once the web reference has been added to the new project, where do I go from there? I have to send a very simple request to the service and get a response even an error response would be good as it shows a connection. I have a wsdl file and a xsd file however not entirely sure how to put everything together.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to generate a client from the WSDL and XSD that describe the service. This ought to be fairly routine.

Comment: So it is possible? Does VWD compile the wsdl file when the application is referenced to the endpoint of the service? If not can you point me in the direction of a walkthrough of how I would generate a client from the wsdl and xsd?

Comment: Google found http://articles.techrepublic.com.com/5100-10878_11-1050426.html and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms464040.aspx (scroll down to "Creating a Windows Application to Consume the Web Service")